# LibAV - what approach to take for realtime audio and video capture?

Tags: audio, encoding, streaming, libav

I'm using libav to encode raw RGB24 frames to h264 and muxing it to flv. This works
all fine and I've streamed for more then 48 hours w/o any problems!  My next step
is to add audio to the stream. I'll be capturing live audio and I want to encode it 
in real time using speex, mp3 or nelly moser.

**Background info**

I'm new to digital audio and therefore I might be doing things wrong. But basically my application gets a "float" buffer with interleaved audio. This "audioIn" function gets called by the application framework I'm using. The buffer contains 256 samples per channel, 
and I have 2 channels. Because I might be mixing terminology, this is how I use the 
data:

```
// input = array with audio samples
// bufferSize = 256
// nChannels = 2
void audioIn(float * input, int bufferSize, int nChannels) {
    // convert from float to S16
        short* buf = new signed short[bufferSize * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < bufferSize; ++i) {  // loop over all samples
        int dx = i * 2;
        buf[dx + 0] = (float)input[dx + 0] * numeric_limits<short>::max();  // convert frame  of the first channel
        buf[dx + 1] = (float)input[dx + 1] * numeric_limits<short>::max();  // convert frame  of the second channel
    }

        // add this to the libav wrapper. 
    av.addAudioFrame((unsigned char*)buf, bufferSize, nChannels);

    delete[] buf;
}
```

Now that I have a buffer, where each sample is 16 bits, I pass this `short* buffer`,  to my 
wrapper `av.addAudioFrame()`  function.  In this function I create a buffer, before I encode 
the audio. From what I read, the `AVCodecContext` of the audio encoder sets the `frame_size`. This frame_size must match the number of samples in the buffer when calling `avcodec_encode_audio2()`.  Why I think this, is because of what is [documented here](http://libav.org/doxygen/master/group__lavc__encoding.html#ga93a49fbd0973b216dcb8a8c5dffe1d82).

Then, especially the line: 
If it is not set, `frame->nb_samples` must be equal to `avctx->frame_size` for all frames except the last.*(Please correct me here if I'm wrong about this).

After encoding I call `av_interleaved_write_frame()` to actually write the frame. 
When I use mp3 as codec my application runs for about 1-2 minutes and then my server, which is receiving the video/audio stream (flv, tcp), disconnects with a message "`Frame too large: 14485504`".  This message is generated because the rtmp-server is getting a frame which is way to big. And this is probably due to the fact I'm not interleaving correctly with libav.

**Questions:**

- There quite some bits I'm not sure of, even when going through the source code of libav and therefore I hope if someone has an working example of encoding audio which comes from a buffer which which comes from "outside" libav (i.e. your own application). i.e. how do you create a buffer which is large enough for the encoder? How do you make the "realtime" streaming work when you need to wait on this buffer to fill up?
- As I wrote above I need to keep track of a buffer before I can encode. Does someone else has some code which does this? I'm using AVAudioFifo now. The functions which encodes the audio and fills/read the buffer is here too: https://gist.github.com/62f717bbaa69ac7196be
- I compiled with --enable-debug=3 and disable optimizations, but I'm not seeing any
  debug information. How can I make libav more verbose?

Thanks!